# Concurrency of three lines in a multiple tangent circles configuration

Tags: geometry, circles, geometric-transformation

Let $ABC$ be a triangle, $\mathcal{C}$ its circumscribed circle and $\mathcal{I}$ its inscribed circle. We construct a circle that is tangent on the interior to $\mathcal{C}$ in the point $A$ and is simultaneously exterior tangent to $\mathcal{I}$ in the point $A'$. Analogously, we obtain the points $B'$ and $C'$. Prove that the lines $AA', BB', CC'$ are concurrent.

[image: LineConcurrency]

I have tried using Ceva's theorem in the triangle $ABC$, by computing the sines of the angles $\angle BAA'$ and $\angle CAA'$, which could have helped to determine the ratio of segments determined by $AA'$ on the side $BC$.

*The problem appeared in a set meant to be solved using geometric transformations, but in this case I don't see exactly how.*

Comment: Thank you for the editing @YNK! Please tell me which software have you used, it looks really performant.

Comment: I used GeoGebra.

Comment: This figure can be found on page 13 of [this booklet: Geometry of the triangle by Paul Yiu](http://gabrielll.altervista.org/libri/Yiu_GeometryoftheTriangle.pdf) with some explanations.

Comment: @YNK Could you share the geogebra script that you have written for obtaining this nice graphics ? I think I have a solution using inversion (oddly called "symmetry" in Geogebra) but I would like to check it first. Thanks !

Comment: @JeanMarie You can download my [Geogebra-Script](https://www.dropbox.com/s/8zgjc2w2kib7dsz/X55.ggb?dl=0) here

Comment: @YNK Thank you very much

Comment: @YNK Seeing the name you have given to your file, it means you have a good understanding of the point in question ! :)

Comment: @JeanMarie Yes, I do have some understanding. This is the $55^\text{th}$ triangle center listed in Kimberling's Encyclopaedia of Triangle Centers. It is called $\bf{\text{Insimilicenter (Circumcircle, Incircle)}}$ and has trilinear coordinates $\bf{1 + \cos \left(A\right) : 1 + \cos\left(B\right) : 1+\cos\left(C\right)}$. It is also the isogonal conjugate of $\bf{\text{Gergonne point}}$ and located on the line that joins $\bf{incenter}$, $\bf{circumcenter}$, and $\bf{X(35)}$ of a given triangle. However, I have not found a proof which is easy to explain.

Answer (score 1):

Inspired by the drawing, I have managed to prove that the lines $AA',BB',CC'$ pass through the same point on the line $OI$, therefore are concurrent.

Denote $CC'\cap OI=\{C''\}$ and with $r_C$ the radius of the circle tangent to $\mathcal{C}$ in $C$ and to $\mathcal{I}$ in $C'$. The following Lemma is useful:

**Lemma:** In a triangle $ABC$ with $D\in BC$ we have $\frac{BD}{CD}=\frac{AB}{AC}\cdot \frac{\sin \angle BAD}{\sin\angle CAD}$.

Aplying the Lemma in $\triangle ICF$ we obtain $\frac{r}{r_C}=\frac{CI}{r_C}\cdot\frac{\sin\angle ICC'}{\sin \angle FCC'}$. Applying the Lemma in $\triangle ICO$ we obtain
$$\frac{IC''}{OC''}=\frac{CI}{R}\cdot\frac{\sin\angle ICC'}{\sin \angle FCC'}=\frac{r}{R},$$
where $r,R$ are the radii of the inscribed and circumscribed circles to the triangle $ABC$. This finishes the proof.